# DELETE FROM where ID = 'user inserted text'?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to delete MySQL rows where id = user inserted text into jTextField in Java. I know I need to use something like `txtGebruikersID.getText();` but not sure how to combine them correctly so that when someone inserts like 25 in JTextField (txtGebruikersID) that value of 25 goes where the 25 is in:

```
query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = 25";
```

Code I use in QueryManager.java:

```
public void removeGebruiker() {
        String query;
        query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = 25";
        dbmanager.insertQuery(query);
    }
```

JTextField is called **txtGebruikersID**

And code I use in userPanel.java:

```
private void removeUserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        WinkelApplication.getInstance().getQueryManager().removeGebruiker();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gebruiker is verwijderd", "Gebruiker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: I **really** hope that the input is sanitized... and that this is an "admin" type tool.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` with bind variables -- this is a years old problem, ie, in computing term, a problem which has been solved in prehistoric times.

Comment: Good god this screams Bobby Tables

Comment: @RobertH reference to XKCD? ;)

Comment: @fge, you got it: for completeness: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Bobby Tables reference and solutions: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Haha was just reading the bobby-tables. It's just for a simple small project. The only one that has access to this delete option will be an Admin.

Comment: @F4LLCON I used to have the same attitude, and then I started reusing my code and propagating flawed code through multiple projects. I spent significantly more time fixing the problems I created then I would have otherwise spent doing it correctly to begin with.

Comment: About the simple small object part? :P I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the function to something like this:

```
public void removeGebruiker(String gebruiker_id) {
    //Some checks here perhaps
    String query;
    query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = " + gebruiker_id;
    dbmanager.insertQuery(query);
}
```

Assuming you have a panel,

```
WinkelApplication.getInstance().getQueryManager().removeGebruiker(TEXTFIELDNAMEHERE.getText());
```

If the user puts 12 into the textfield the resulting query will be:

```
delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = 12
```

Nevertheless there are better ways to do this. Prepared statements are indeed better. If you do use this method make sure to check the input from the user.

Comment: Awesome, this worked. Thank you for your time. Will accept in 4 minutes

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this. This is more preferred way on working with sqls

```
query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query); // con is active connection
st.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(txtGebruikersID.getText()));
```

[What is SQL Injection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks, but what is wrong with the code from Floris Velleman?

Comment: The code below is open to SQL injection per our comments above.

Comment: The code given by Floris will also work but that will not avoid `SQL injection`. [What is SQL Injection?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @F4LLCON: Something that works need not mean that it is the best solution. Look at the flaw that others have pointed out and I'm sure you would appreciate the importance of using `PreparedStatement` instead of the way that you've currently implemented :)

Comment: @F4LLCON You should definitely take a look at `SQL injection`.  I have added that link in my answer. It will help you in future.

Comment: @smit thank you, But SQL injection don't work in windows applications right? I mean the only one accessing the database is the admin, and I don't think the admin will destroy his own work? Well he can access the database without the application, so why should he inject? I know that when working with Java for web or PHP for example, injections are bad

Comment: @F4LLCON I don't know how to answer this question. But hackers are hackers and they always know how to breach online security and about your admin I can't make any comments.